# D3.js How to evenly distribute values on x axis?

Tags: d3.js

I have a specific set of values for example :

```
[1, 4, 12, 32, 150, 250]
```

How can I display them on a x axis but with the same gap between each ticks ?
For the momvent by specifying tickvalues to the axis with a linear scale I obtain something like that

```
1-4--12---32-------150----------250
```

But I am searching to obtain something like that :

```
1--4--12--32--150--250
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: You could not give ticks explicitly and let D3 figure it out.

Comment: Thanks but if I do that I will not have control on what is displayed on each ticks...

Comment: Ok I managed to do what I wanted using ordinal scales https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales